# Is there a way to whitelist which types are allowed in a template function?

Tags: c++

I have a template function that I would like to only work with a specific list of types.

```
 template <class T> void foo(const T f) {/*do stuff with f*/}

 int main() {
        string A= "Hello world";
        char B[10] = "Hello world";
        Int C = 69;

        foo(A); //should work here
        foo(B); //and here
        foo(C); //but it should give an error here, preferably while it is compiling

       return 0;
 }
```

I expect it to work if I call it with a char[] or with a string, but give an error (possibly while it's compiling, but during runtime works too) when I try to call it with an INT type.

Comment: Can you tell us more about `/*do stuff with f*/` entails? This information is crucial to understanding what the best options are, and whether templates are the appropriate solution to begin with.

Comment: Perhaps just make it a regular/non-templated function that takes a string argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SFINAE might help:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<int, T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(const T f) {/*do stuff with f*/}
```

or

```
template <class T,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::string, T>::value
                           || std::is_same<const char*, T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(const T f) {/*do stuff with f*/}
```

Adjust the condition to your needs.

or `static_assert`:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const T f) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::string, T>::value
                  || std::is_same<const char*, T>::value, "Incorrect type");
    /*do stuff with f*/
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For your particular case, I would overload the function `foo` instead of using a template. This ensures you can *only* have one of those two types, and with those two types in particular it is quite simple to overload:

```
void foo(const char* s) {
    // do work with s
}

void foo(const std::string& s) {
    foo(s.c_str()); // use the other overload for const char*
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can still pass `0` to the function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 a *compile-time literal* of `0` (and ONLY `0`) can be assigned *directly* to ANY pointer, such as `char*`. This is for backwards compatibility with C and pre-C++11 before `nullptr` was introduced. Given the two overloads above, `foo(0)` will call `foo(const char*)` with a null `char*` pointer. However, an `int` variable whose *runtime value* is `0` cannot be assigned directly to a pointer, it must be type-casted explicitly. So `int C = 0; foo(C);` will not compile, but `foo((char*)C)` and `foo(reinterpret_cast<char*>(C))` will.

Answer (score 6):

For this particular case the easiest way is to just use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) from C++17.  Not only will this accept a `std::string` or a char array, but it will also accept a `char*` plus size, and anything that provides an `operator string_view()`.

That would give you

```
void foo(std::string_view sv) 
{
    //do stuff with sv
}
```

If you are asking in general, then you can either overload the function, or use SFINAE like

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, some_type> ||
                                    std::is_same_v<T, some_other_type> ||
                                    std::is_same_v<T, even_more>, bool> = true> 
void foo(const T f) {/*do stuff with f*/}
```

Comment: Good to know about `std::string_view`. I have yet to play much with a lot of the new features of C++17. This is definitely the way OP should go in this case :)